# RavenDB Authentication and Authorization

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, ravendb

I am a SQL Server DBA trying to undestand the working of RavenDB Security . If I want to design an application security ,I will use a single system user and one application user for each actual user .

The question that I have is  that how will I be able to set the context of the application user . I need to supply the application user name and the Operation to the SecureFor() .However from where will I be able to get the application user (the user who has logged in)  information without hardcoding it within the application .

The examples that I see in the RavenDB site is with hardcoded users in the SecureFor but in real life, I will presume that the user name will be related to the actual user which will be dynamic .

Regards,
Venky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are talking about the [Authorization Bundle page within the RavenDB Documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/authorization).

You haven't talked any about the problem domain, so I think first I should mention that my preference would be to **not use** the Authorization Bundle at all. Because [there is a difference between system users and application users](http://ayende.com/blog/121857/system-users-and-application-users), in most software systems you should allow the system user 100% read/write access to the database, and control what application users have access to using application logic.

That being said, I don't want to argue the point too much. Let's assume that you do have verifiable need of the authorization bundle.

The operation you will define yourself according to your business rules. I presume you understand that already because you are not asking where that will come from in your question.

The user has to be defined from the context in which the code is running. Basically, authentication is a separate concern.

From an ASP.NET web application, you would either use Windows Authentication in a domain environment to get the users' Windows identity, or perhaps Forms Authentication to get identities stored within your own application. You can get then get the identity of the current user through the guts of ASP.NET. (The best way to access it is different based on if you are coming from Web Forms, MVC, WebAPI, etc.) How you translate the current user into an authorization user string (the `Authorization/Users/DrHowser` in the example from the docs) is up to you.

Comment: Thanks David for the very clear explanation . I did have a follow-up question .

Comment: Thanks David for that very clear explanation . I did have a follow-up question . I was under the impression that the application user (user from the authroization bundle) needs to be verified like the application users in SQL Server but I now understand that the RavenDB just beleives the User ID mentioned in the SecureFor() .Is that correct ? Thanks again , Venky

Comment: Yes, you still need to authorize (verify the credentials of) the incoming user. This is the fundamental difference between authentication and authorization. The RavenDB bundle only does authorization assuming you have already verified the user's identity.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following interesting. ASP.NET Identity is a new membership for ASP.NET. ASP.NET Identity lets you add basic login/ logout functionality and also provides first class support for persisting your membership information in a Non SQL store. By default ASP.NET Identity uses EF, but you can easily replace this layer with RavenDb without changing your code.
You can take a look at an RavenDb implementation for ASP.NET Identity here https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNet.Identity.RavenDB
It shows that if you have an MVC application you can replace the storage of your membership information from EF to RavenDb by just registering the RavenDb store instead of EF.
If you want more information about ASP.NET Identity, please visit http://asp.net/identity